# adding a unique identifier

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with n rows. I would like to add a column which will identify every row (same letter). How can I do this? I need this for a Kruskal Wallis test.

df1

```
x1
1
2
3
```

output

df1

```
value variable

a  1
a  2
a  3
```

Comment: I don't think that's encouraged(likely to throw an error). Maybe add it as a column instead?

Comment: Adding a constant to every row doesn't "identify" anything from a data perspective. Could you explain what makes you think this is necessary? I suspect the "real" underlying problem might better be solved a different way.

Comment: Are you looking for `df1$value <- "a"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
df1$value <- "a"
df1$variable <- df1$x1
df$x1 <- NULL
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
rename(variable = x1) %>%
mutate(value = "a")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `transmute`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   transmute(value = 'a', variable = x1)
#  value variable
#1     a        1
#2     a        2
#3     a        3
```